# Disable comment and like in posts whith trigger?

Tags: trigger, force.com, salesforce-id

how i can use trriger to disable comments ans likes in a posts of an group

```
trigger groupInactif on "?" (befor insert)
```

thx.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Understand that your question is quite limited and without much detail of things you have already tried, which makes it hard to give you a very good answer.

Comment: I have do it for comments and posts bu no solution for Liks

Answer (score 3):

Going by the [Chatter Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_chatter/chatter.pdf), you'll want to define the trigger on FeedItem. Blocking comments should be easy since the FeedItem for comments will have their ParentId field set. I'm not sure if you can stop a Like, though.

One thing to keep in mind: blocking comments and likes will disable a lot of the functionality that makes Chatter useful. If you just want to broadcast announcements you may want to consider a different technology.

Comment: hi, what i want it's to bloque all changement in some of groups (group.Name= '*inactif'), and let her history